# Alignment with \underbrace

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

I want to put the right sides of the four equations to be under each other, so the e^(...) should be under each other in each column. I don't get this because of the `\underbrace`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eqn:4}
\begin{alignedat}{4}
&\eta(z+1)^{4}&&=e^{\frac{\pi i}{3}}\eta(z)^{4}, &\quad\quad&\phantom{~}& \eta(2(z+1))^{8}&=e^{\frac{4\pi i}{3}}\eta(2z)^{8},\\
&\eta(3(z+1))^{4}&&=\underbrace{e^{\pi i}}_{=-1}\eta(3z)^{4}, &&\phantom{~}& \eta(6(z+1))^{8}&=\underbrace{e^{4\pi i}}_{=1}\eta(6z)^{8}.
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How do you want the upper terms, e.g., `e^{\frac{4\pi i}{3}`, to be aligned with respect to the lower, wider terms? Flush-left, centered, or flush-right? Please advise.

Comment: I don't get what you are asking. There are four equations placed in two columns, these two columns each have `e^(..)` expressions one on top of each other... Can you be more specific of what is the problem and the desired format?

Comment: If you look at one column, you'll see that the lower e^(...) is more on the right than the upper one because of the underbrace. This is my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `eqparbox`, with some tweaks:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eqparbox}                   

\newcommand{\matheqparbox}[2]{%
  \eqparbox[t]{#1}{\hfil$\displaystyle#2$\hfil}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eqn:4}
\begin{alignedat}{4}
&\eta(z+1)^{4}&&=\matheqparbox{1}{e^{\frac{\pi i}{3}}}\eta(z)^{4},
  &\quad\quad&
  & \eta(2(z+1))^{8}&=\matheqparbox{2}{e^{\frac{4\pi i}{3}}}\eta(2z)^{8},\\
&\eta(3(z+1))^{4}&&=\matheqparbox{1}{\underbrace{e^{\pi i}}_{=-1}\,}\eta(3z)^{4},
  &&
  & \eta(6(z+1))^{8}&=\matheqparbox{2}{\underbrace{e^{4\pi i}}_{=1}\,}\eta(6z)^{8}.
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The command `\eqparbox` needs a label for computing the maximum width of the boxes with the same label. Here I used `1` and `2`, but they can be any (unique) string.

[image]

On the other hand, I'd prefer right alignment before the equals signs:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\newcommand{\matheqparbox}[2]{%
  \eqparbox[t]{#1}{\hfil$\displaystyle#2$\hfil}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eqn:4}
\begin{aligned}
\eta(z+1)^{4}&=\matheqparbox{1}{e^{\frac{\pi i}{3}}}\eta(z)^{4},
  & \eta(2(z+1))^{8}&=\matheqparbox{2}{e^{\frac{4\pi i}{3}}}\eta(2z)^{8},\\
\eta(3(z+1))^{4}&=\matheqparbox{1}{\underbrace{e^{\pi i}}_{=-1}\,}\eta(3z)^{4},
  & \eta(6(z+1))^{8}&=\matheqparbox{2}{\underbrace{e^{4\pi i}}_{=1}\,}\eta(6z)^{8}.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For maximum flexibility, you may want to use an `array` environment. In the following solution, I've assumed you want the `e^{...}` terms centered across rows. Feel free to switch from `C` to either `L` or `R` if you prefer left- or right-alignment instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for general math typesetting support
\usepackage{array}    % for "\newcolumntype" macro
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\displaystyle}c}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\displaystyle}l}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\displaystyle}r}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eqn:4}
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{array}{ R@{{}={}}C@{\kern1pt}L @{\hspace{2em}} 
               R@{{}={}}C@{\kern1pt}L }
\eta(z+1)^{4}    & e^{\frac{\pi i}{3}}          & \eta(z)^{4},  &
\eta(2(z+1))^{8} & e^{\frac{4\pi i}{3}}         & \eta(2z)^{8}, \\
\eta(3(z+1))^{4} & \underbrace{e^{\pi i}}_{=-1} & \eta(3z)^{4}, &
\eta(6(z+1))^{8} & \underbrace{e^{4\pi i}}_{=1} & \eta(6z)^{8}.
\end{array}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! What can I do if I want the \eta in the left column on the left be also under each other?

Comment: @user372565 - if the entire expression `\eta(z+1)^{4}` should be left-aligned in its column, change `R` to `L` in the column definition. If you want just the first `\eta` symbol in the first row to be above the one in the second row, what's supposed to be done with the `(z+1)^{4}` term? Should it stay where it is right now? Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}\label{eqn:4}
\begin{aligned}
\eta(z+1)^{4}   &= e^{\frac{\pi i}{3}} \eta(z)^{4},    & 
\eta(2(z+1))^{8}&= e^{\frac{4\pi i}{3}}\eta(2z)^{8}, \\
\eta(3(z+1))^{4}&= \mkern-5mu\underbrace{e^{\pi i}}_{=-1} \eta(3z)^{4},   &
\eta(6(z+1))^{8}&= \underbrace{e^{4\pi i}}_{=1} \eta(6z)^{8}.
\end{aligned}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This method does not appear to align the `\eta` symbols on the RHSs of the equations, whichs is (I assume!) one of the OP's formatting objectives.